# Exporting graphics in .emf format in SPSS causes false encoding of the titles

Tags: graphics, export, spss, .emf

I'm using SPSS 21 (on Windows 7) to create some descriptive reports. I want to export my graphics in the best format for word processing. I found that the .emf format works well, i.e. the graphs are quite good when I insert them into a word document.

The only problem is: in the graphs titles, there are some umlauts (german characters like ä, ö, ü) and some accents (french characters like é, à, è. etc), and when I export the graphs, it displays these umlauts and accents as Ã¼, Ã etc.

I already change (manually) the encoding of the Data and Syntax (in Options of SPSS) and choose the "Unicode" one. But even by changing this encoding, the titles of my graphs are not correctly encoded through the exportation.

Do you have any ideas why ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: (First post review - well asked) Are you able to include an example of one of the files in question?  This may help.

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug to SPSS. I don't know the support for Unicode in emf. A workaround might be to save to high resolution PNG files - do the accents export correctly in other formats?

Comment: Yes, @AndyW, in others formats, the accents are correctly exported. The thing is, with others formats, such as png files, you don't have the possibility to modify the resolution in which you want to export the graph and this results in bad bad images with bad bad resolution. This is why I think the .emf format is the best format for exporting in SPSS. You're right, I will search more information and report this as a bug to SPSS. By the way, I found that another possibility is... either so work with R :-) either to export in .eps format. It's working also very well with a very good resolution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was reported recently (introduced in the course of fixing another bug :-)) and has been fixed for a future release.

Comment: Indeed, it was a bug that was fixed in the SPSS 22 version ! I've just installed and this works great!